# Set tab bar item selected image in xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode6, uitabbar

This is my setup for a tab bar item:

[image]

However when clicking on the item inside the app the 1051-id-badge-selected image is not shown, instead nothing is shown:

[image]

Is something wrong with my setup? Any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To get around this issue and set selected image without writing any code, we can also use "User Defined Run Attributes".

[image]

Select the tab bar item, then in 'Identity Inspector', add a new value from 'User Defined Runtime Attributes'.

Set the 'Key Path' to `selectedImage`, and choose 'Type' `Image`, then fill in the 'Value' with your image name.

---

If the inspector solution is not working for you (e.g. because of an Xcode bug) you can try this solution. In AppDelegate:

```
var tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as UITabBarController
let tabItems = tabBarController.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]

tabItems[2].selectedImage = UIImage(named: "1051-id-badge-selected.png")
```

Update on May 25, 2016:

On Xcode 7.3.1 the `Selected Image` field under `Tab Bar Item` section is working correctly. (But I don't know from which exact version Apple fixed it for Xcode).

Comment: code segment is better then trying to understand the Xcode problems