# Change tintColor of unselected UITabBarController item title and background image

Tags: ios, ios8, uitabbaritem, tintcolor, bartintcolor

How can I change the tintColor of an unselected UITabBarItem title and background image iOS 8?

The default color for an unselected state is a light gray color, but it does not show on my darkish shade UITabBar background

I'd like my unselected state to have a color of [UIColor blackColor]

Inside my app delegate didfinishlaunchingwithoptions: I have

```
UIImage *deselectedE = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"mincraft_axe_green_32.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic];
UIImage *selectedE = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"mincraft_axe_green_32.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic];
e.tabBarItem =  [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Profile" image:deselectedE selectedImage:selectedE];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: in iOS 10+ and swift 3 you can do `tabBarCtrl.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.gray`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40741444/1652402

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Figured it out!

Use this to change the color of the text:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor] }
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor] }
                                         forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

And make sure that image rendering mode is set to ORIGINAL for the images

```
UIImage *deselectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselectedImage"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIImage *selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImage"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Comment: Original images is a nice thing. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: What if my original icon is black but I want it to be white?

Comment: I had a similar situation where, but I wanted my unselected image to be white (original image is white) and my selected image to be yellow (currently grey). I'm sure his solution above works if I was willing to alter the color of my selected image, but I wanted to use the built-in "tint color" property for the selected image. When I tried putting my selected image in the attributes inspector under Tab bar Item, it left the image blank at runtime (bug). I used this solution in my app delegate: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515703/set-tab-bar-item-selected-image-in-xcode-6)

Comment: @ReneeOlson it does feel a bit hacky but it does work. Glad it helped you a bit :)

Comment: cannot believe you have to pre-render the tint in iOS 8. Such a step backwards! But thanks! Any way of implementing this in a Storyboard?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working on iOS 13/XCode 11.x

Answer (score 27):

In your AppDelegate.m inside of `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` use the following code:

```
//unselected icon tint color 
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITabBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

//selected tint color 
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

//text tint color 
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] }
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//background tint color 
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Comment: Changing the unselected tint color changes back after that item has been selected then unselected. It seems that the only way to get the unselected state to be the color you want is by using your own image. You can see how to do that here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19662170/4114683

Comment: I tried and found out that you can also use `[[UIButton appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];` to keep consistency between selected tab bar items and button labels in iOS 7/8 (e.g. like the Music app)

Comment: Work like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this has been deprecated in later versions.

Comment: [[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITabBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
 is not only deprecated but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 14):

You can also render the image as original from the attributes inspector for the asset file without writing any code

[image]

Comment: It's not from the storyboard, but from the Attributes Inspector for the asset file. Other than that, this is the best answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set it up directly in Storyboard... Check my answer here: 
[How to set UITabBarItem's unselected tint, ***including system items*** (iOS7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018242/how-to-set-uitabbaritems-unselected-tint-including-system-items-ios7)

> If you're using Storyboard you can also set both `Image` for `Bar Item` and `Selected Image` for `Selected Bar Item` to get unaltered image in tabBar.

Alternatively in `Assets` catalog, you can select `Render As`: `Original Image` in the attributes of your image (`View` > `Utilities` > `Show Attributes Inspector` or shortcut `⌥⌘4` (Option + Command + 4))