# Change color of unselected tabbar item image without making it original

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitabbaritem

I have followed this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551458/change-tintcolor-of-unselected-uitabbarcontroller-item-title-and-background-imag)
it is working fine for UITabBar item text but if I use original images  then I am unable to change color for selected UITabBar item image

I am changing image tint color and making it original through storyBoard not programmatically i.e "selectedImageTintColor" (this is changing tabbar item image color on selection for template image not for original  )

Answer (score 0):

#### updated to Swift 3

## Use this code inside UITabbarcontroller

```
    //User this line for selected Tabbar Image tint colour

    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.purple

    // You can set tab colours as per requirement here
    // set red as selected background color
    let numberOfItems = CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
    let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / numberOfItems, height: tabBar.frame.height)
    tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: UIColor.red, size: tabBarItemSize).resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero)

    // remove default border
    tabBar.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width + 4
    tabBar.frame.origin.x = -2
```

### And Use this extension for Image color

```
extension UIImage {
    class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
       let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: size.width,height: size.height)
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
       color.setFill()
       UIRectFill(rect)
       let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
       return image
   }
}
```

Comment: sorry, you miss understand the question. I need for not selected tabbar item image

Comment: you used this code line inside UITabbarcontroller  :-UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()