# Set colourful images in default uitabbar for both selected and deselected stats

Tags: ios, swift2, uitabbar

[current tabbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSDM9.png)

[expected tabbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG585.png)

How can we set colourful images to default uitabbaritem for selected and deselected stats.

Comment: r u using storyboard ? Info you provided is too broad. Show what you have tried.

Comment: yes, i'm using storyboard. i tried many ways but not getting expected result. i take one tab bar controller and set background image as green color which seeing in above image. but i want to add image of uitabbaritem as above home, download and like images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set tab bar item selected image in xcode 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515703/set-tab-bar-item-selected-image-in-xcode-6)

Comment: i tried this but it's not working. i'm using swift 2.0 and Xcode  7.1

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of your storybaord tab bar ?

Comment: add the image to your question

Comment: can you see both images in my questions?

Comment: Yes. If you dont want to apply the tint color when you tap on the tab bar item,make the tab bar tint color as clear color

Comment: yes it's ok but images not showing as original. my tabor tint color is blue now. but yet showing green color, when any tabbaritem selected

Comment: you posted two different tab bars. Which one are you referring to ? pls show the tab bar before and after selecting the tab bar

Comment: y dont u simply replace the images with the colored images ?

Comment: no, i can't  that is problem.

Comment: if you have any demo related this then send me.

Comment: So, you want a green background TabBar with bar item images that you provided in **expected tab bar** Image ?

Comment: yes. exactly i want to make, i want to use colourful images in uitabbaritem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the background color of UITabBar using barTintColor

```
//Sample color codes
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 10, green: 10, blue: 10, alpha: 1.0))
```

And you can set bar items normal and selected images using an iteration over tabBar's items

```
    for barItem in (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items)! {

        // Default image
        barItem.image = UIImage(named: "home")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)

        // By default Selected image will take tint color set in self.tabBar.tintColor
        barItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "home_selected")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
    }
```

By settings image's rendering mode as AlwaysOriginal you can ensure that the tint color's do not effect the image.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, create an `UITabBarController` and in your storyboard set it as the class of your tabbar controller , darg the tabBar and create an outlet let's say mainTabBar then override `viewWillAppear` method and put this inside it.

```
for item in mainTabBar.items!{

        item.image = item.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
        item.selectedImage = item.image
    }
```

dont forget to call `super.viewWillAppear(animated)` at the end

Comment: and where to set colourful images in tabbaritems?

Comment: set them in your storyboard. If you use this method you will have same tabbaricon for selected and unselected states

Comment: i use this method but when tabbaritem is selected it showing nothing and when it deselected it show white coloured image.

Comment: Thank you Coyote for your kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass UITabBarController and manually set each image for each state.

For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [(self.tabBar.items)[0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"colorfulHouse"]];
    [(self.tabBar.items)[0] setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"colorfulHouseSelected"]];

    [(self.tabBar.items)[1] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"colorfulRecyclingBin"]];
    [(self.tabBar.items)[1] setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"colorfulRecyclingBinSelected"]];
}
```

Comment: can you make it in swift version?